# Is this not a circular dependency in NX Vite plugin?

Tags: node-modules, yarn-lock.json, nx-monorepo

Didn't want to file a github issue with @nx/vite because it seems to work, but I'm not sure how yarn doesn't complain when installing, so I'd like to know why.

I noticed [here](https://nx.dev/recipes/other/rescope) that they're rescoping. It says that @nrwl scoped packages have exported their @nx counterparts. But how does that work if the @nrwl scoped package is a dependency of the @nx package?

```
"@nrwl/vite@16.5.5":
  version "16.5.5"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@nrwl/vite/-/vite-16.5.5.tgz#60aa0ff52d515bdfbf5ca2e89471962da6481b18"
  integrity sha512-ZVXDnYGy9nj33QumZwA8/yzVDTq414pZfQSVDH49iSFB0MbK1mki8C4bvpYOtK/qke2un1LSeyasUpASwTfAiQ==
  dependencies:
    "@nx/vite" "16.5.5"
...
"@nx/vite@16.5.5":
  version "16.5.5"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@nx/vite/-/vite-16.5.5.tgz#ccc1bfa2c13ab009a0ad6d4ad0291b9314d42992"
  integrity sha512-oWKAsy2tmiuThZWv8WHnomX4kw3+9Y+BWQgbGBbNkr+PrNYwkmY8GZ2DyFA1YRK/EwBnQkeLXxbIMk6MIbh10Q==
  dependencies:
    "@nrwl/vite" "16.5.5"
    ...
```

Everything works as expected, I'm just not sure why. I looked up an article from the publisher explaining their rescoping effort and what they did, but it doesn't explain why it works.